# Flutter not loading all SVG's correctly

Tags: flutter, dart, svg

I have a problem with some of my SVG-Assets, they are not loading correctly:

> flutter: unhandled element pattern; Picture key: AssetBundlePictureKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#bc01d(), name: "assets/images/list_images/avocado.svg", colorFilter: null)
>
> flutter: Another exception was thrown: Failed to find definition for
> url(#pattern0)

[image]   [image]

These are my `paths`:

```
`class ListImagePath {
  static const avocado = "assets/images/list_images/avocado.svg";
  static const balloon = "assets/images/list_images/balloon.svg";
  static const beer = "assets/images/list_images/beer.svg";
  static const bike = "assets/images/list_images/bike.svg";
  static const book = "assets/images/list_images/book.svg";
  static const christmas = "assets/images/list_images/christmas.svg";
  static const dress = "assets/images/list_images/dress.svg";
  static const egg = "assets/images/list_images/egg.svg";
  static const furniture = "assets/images/list_images/furniture.svg";
  static const gift_1 = "assets/images/list_images/gift_1.svg";
  static const gift_2 = "assets/images/list_images/gift_2.svg";
  static const goals = "assets/images/list_images/goals.svg";
  static const main = "assets/images/list_images/main.svg";
  static const roller = "assets/images/list_images/roller.svg";
  static const shirt = "assets/images/list_images/shirt.svg";
  static const shoe = "assets/images/list_images/shoe.svg";
  static const technik = "assets/images/list_images/technik.svg";
  static const travel = "assets/images/list_images/travel.svg";
  static const wine = "assets/images/list_images/wine.svg";

  static const defaultImagePath = "assets/images/list_images/default.svg";
}`
```

And my `pubspec`:

```
flutter:

    uses-material-design: true
    
      assets:
         - assets/images/background_images/
         - assets/images/list_images/
```

What am I missing here? Is this a common Flutter_SVG bug? How can I fix this?

Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with Flutter Web and I had to downgrade recently:

```
flutter channel beta
flutter downgrade 1.25.0-8.3.pre
```

because 1.26.0-17.3.pre seems to be broken with respect to SVGs:
code like Image.network("assets/cube.svg")
causes

```
======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following ImageCodecException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Failed to decode image data.
Image source: http://localhost:45923/assets/cube.svg

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 236:49      throw_
lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/image.dart 102:7                                     createDefault
lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/skia_object_cache.dart 141:41                        new
lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/image.dart 92:3                                      decodeFromBytes
lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/image.dart 75:53                                     <fn>
...
Image provider: NetworkImage("assets/cube.svg", scale: 1)
Image key: NetworkImage("assets/cube.svg", scale: 1)
```

I don't know whether it's fixed in the most recent version